# Using addDecorator in Storybook's preview.ts throws Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: reactjs, storybook, chromatic

Reading through the resource loading documentation from Chromatic, the [Solution B: Check fonts have loaded in a decorator](https://www.chromatic.com/docs/resource-loading#solution-b-check-fonts-have-loaded-in-a-decorator) section.

Mainly would like to load our fonts before rendering the stories. The solution suggest to use `addDecorator` where with a simple `FC` we can preload the fonts and once they are loaded it can render the stories with `story()`.

See the suggested decorator for `preview.ts`:

```
import isChromatic from "chromatic/isChromatic";

if (isChromatic() && document.fonts) {
  addDecorator((story) => {
    const [isLoadingFonts, setIsLoadingFonts] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
      Promise.all([document.fonts.load("1em Roboto")]).then(() =>
        setIsLoadingFonts(false)
      );
    }, []);

    return isLoadingFonts ? null : story();
  });
}
```

For some reason this throws the usual error when violating the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html):

> Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

[image: screenshot]

**What I've tried so far:**

Mainly I tried to remove the `useEffect` which renders the stories:

```
if (isChromatic() && document.fonts) {
  addDecorator((story) => {
    const [isLoadingFonts, setIsLoadingFonts] = useState(true);
   
    return story();
  });
}
```

Also the error disappeared but the fonts are causing inconsistent changes our screenshot tests as before.

**Question:**

I don't really see any issues which would violate the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) in the added `FC` for the `addDecorator`.

Is there anything what can make this error disappear? I'm open to any suggestions. Maybe I missed something here, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly what solved the issue on our end is removing from `main.ts` one of the `addons` called `@storybook/addon-knobs`.

Also renamed from `preview.ts` to `preview.tsx` and used the decorator a bit differently as the following:

```
export const decorators = [
  Story => {
    const [isLoadingFonts, setIsLoadingFonts] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
      const call = async () => {
        await document.fonts.load('1em Roboto')

        setIsLoadingFonts(false)
      }

      call()
    }, [])

    return isLoadingFonts ? <>Fonts are loading...</> : <Story />
  },
]
```

We dropped using the `addDecorator` and used as the exported `const decorators` as above.